# Use Typescript model as an Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some models defined and I want to use the type that is going to be assigned as an array. I get a result from an api call and make a new instance of my `type` but the result is an array how can I make this work?

If I assign the variable `parents = new Parents()` and then try and use this in Angular in an `ngFor` it complains about only use `arrays...`

If I assign `parents:any` it works fine? Im not getting it yet.

```
  parents =  new Parent();
```

then after api returns with data

```
  this.parents = this.user.parents;
```

which is an array

```
export class Parent {
 id: number;
 email: string;
 title: string;
 first_name: string;
 last_name: string;
 profile_image: string;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you are doing. In TypeScript, your array should just be `parents: MyType[];`

Comment: `ngFor` is an Angular 2+ construct; not AngularJS.

Comment: Sorry it is Angular 2

Comment: If parents is supposed to be an empty array before the API returns a value, you should initialize it to `[]`: `parents: Array<Parent> = [];`. If it should just be undefined before the API returns, then don't initialize it: `parents: Array<Parent>;`. An array of parents is different from a parent. Just like a box built to contain eggs is not an egg.

Comment: I have tried this then the class want to implement all members, pop(), push(), shift() etc.., seems a bit more than I expected. Thanks for your help, I need to do more learning of Typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. implements the Array

   ```
   export class Parent implements Array<any>{ }
   ```
2. Loop through the properties of Parent in your ngFor

   ```
   <span *ngFor="let prop of props">{{parent[prop]}}</span>
   ```

where `props = Object.keys(parent)`